# How can I nested my code that aim to add "onClick" function in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

this is my vanilla js code for manipulate the DOM. On top part it work perfectly fine. But i want to learn how to shrink down this code

```
 // this code is small part of "Calculator website" project.

 const numInput = (num) => {

    // .. another condition ..

    monitorNum.innerText = (monitorNum.innerText * 10) + num;
 };


    // i want to shrink down the code at below.

 document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(1);
  })
  document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(2);
  })
  document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(3);
  })
  document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(4);
  })
  document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(5);
  })
  document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(6);
  })
  document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(7);
  })
  document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(8);
  })
  document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(9);
  })
  document.getElementById("o").addEventListener("click", () => {
    numInput(0);
  })
```

at first I try some forEach. But look like I'm not understand js enough.

```
// I try to make obj and get it forEach with object.entries. But it's not how it work.

const numberObj = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3,
    "four": 4,
    "five": 5,
    "six": 6,
    "seven": 7,
    "eight": 8,
    "nine": 9,
    "o": 0
  }

  object.entries(numberObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    document.getElementById(key).addEventListener("click", () => {
      numInput(value);
    })
  })
```

Can you give me some suggestion or any knowledge about this situation.
Thank you in advance.

I try to use object and forEach method for add even listener to manipulate DOM object.
but each object not respond with my "object.entries & forEach" code at all.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: for display number I have <div id=" monitor" class="full-monitor"></div>
and for number button part we have 10x of this but id and text inside and the change of text inside <button id="one" class="white-button">1</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. This is a way to do it:

```js
const numberObj = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3,
    "four": 4,
    "five": 5,
    "six": 6,
    "seven": 7,
    "eight": 8,
    "nine": 9,
    "zero": 0
  }
  
  var monitorNum = 0;

  numInput = (num) => {
      monitorNum = (monitorNum * 10) + parseInt(num);
      document.getElementById('monitor').innerHTML = monitorNum;
  };

  Object.entries(numberObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    document.getElementById(key).addEventListener("click", () => {
      numInput(value);
    })
  })
```

```html
<div id="monitor">-</div>

<button id='one'>1</button>
<button id='two'>2</button>
<button id='three'>3</button>
<button id='four'>4</button>
<button id='five'>5</button>
<button id='six'>6</button>
<button id='seven'>7</button>
<button id='eight'>8</button>
<button id='nine'>9</button>
<button id='zero'>0</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm too embarrassed because I missed the "O" on "object".  and I'm looking forward for your respond.

Comment: There you go. I think this is enough to get you going :)

Comment: I used Object.entries because you're obviously learning js. But when you're ready, I advise you to study @code 's response. As `[...document.getElementById("parent").childNodes]` is a much better way to get the objects.

Comment: ok I will learn and apply ... notation at my project right now. thank for your kindly help!

Answer (score 2):

You can first create an array, where each number is associated with its word:

```js
const list = ["o", "one", "two", "three", ...]
//             0    1      2      3
```

Now, you can loop through the list and use the index for the number to pass to your function:

```js
list.forEach((name, index) =>
  document.getElementById(name).addEventListener("click", () => numInput(index))
)
```

However, assuming your HTML has the format (they don't have to be divs, they can be any other element):

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="o">...</div>
  <div id="one">...</div>
  <div id="two">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

You can simply get the child elements of the parent:

```js
[...document.getElementById("parent").childNodes].forEach((el, index) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", () => numInput(index))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array or anything complicated. You can simply give each button a data-attribute for the value that needs to be passed to the function. Then delegate the click to the body and look for that dataset value.

```js
let monitorNum = document.querySelector("#monitorNum");
let val = 0;
const numInput = (num) => {
    val = num + (val * 10);
    monitorNum.innerHTML = val;
 };

document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if(el.dataset.value){
    numInput(parseInt(el.dataset.value));
  }
});
```

```html
<button data-value="1" class="btn">1</button>
<button data-value="2" class="btn">2</button>
<button data-value="3" class="btn">3</button>
<button data-value="4" class="btn">4</button>
<button data-value="5" class="btn">5</button>
<button data-value="6" class="btn">6</button>
<button data-value="7" class="btn">7</button>
<button data-value="8" class="btn">8</button>
<button data-value="9" class="btn">9</button>
<button data-value="0" class="btn">0</button>
<div id="monitorNum">0</div>
```